# MLPClassifier: Expected 2D array got 1D array instead

Tags: python, arrays

Sup guys, I'm new to Python and new to Neural Networks as well. I'm trying to implement a Neural Network to predict the Close price of Bitcoin in a day, based on Open price in the same day. So I get a CSV file, and I'm trying to use 'Open' column as entry, and 'Close' column as target, you can see this in the code below:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('BTC_USD.csv')

X = dataset['Open']
y = dataset['Close']

NeuralNetwork = MLPClassifier(verbose = True,
                       max_iter = 1000,
                       tol = 0,
                       activation = 'logistic')

NeuralNetwork.fit(X, y)
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   array=[4.95100000e-02 4.95100000e-02 8.58400000e-02 ... 6.70745996e+03
>    6.66883984e+03 7.32675977e+03].
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

After this error, I did some research here in stackoverflow, and I tried some solutions proposed in other posts, like this one:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('BTC_USD.csv')

X = np.array(dataset[['Open']])
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

y = np.array(dataset[['Close']])
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

NeuralNetwork = MLPClassifier(verbose = True,
                       max_iter = 1000,
                       tol = 0,
                       activation = 'logistic')

NeuralNetwork.fit(X, y)
```

After running this code, I get this new error:

> ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([4.95100000e-02, 8.58400000e-02, 8.08000000e-02, ...,
>   6.66883984e+03, 6.30685010e+03, 7.49379980e+03]),)

and this ''warning'' at the first line (which contains the directory):

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
>   y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

Could you help me please? I tried many solutions, but any of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion provided in the error? More precisely, add ```y = y.ravel()``` right before the fitting or directly do ```NeuralNetwork.fit(X, y.ravel())```.

Comment: No I didn't, but I tried it right now and returned this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rave1'

Comment: It is ```ravel()``` with an L, not a 1.

Comment: hahaha sorry bro, but It didn't work anyway.. I don't know what to do anymore about this

Comment: Could you provide the data set so we can check?

Comment: I imported this CSV from yahoo finance, could you download it and try to run the same code in your PC ? How can I attach this here CSV here ?

Comment: Provide the link where to download the file.

Comment: This one mate: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k3k2qq5m0EoU0OYGikkkk95bM6LebHrt 
Uploaded it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `values` attribute of a data frame to get the elements of one column. In addition, what you want to achieve is a regression, not a classification, thus you must use a regressor such as `MLPRegressor`, following

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('BTC_USD.csv')

X = dataset["Open"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = dataset["Close"].values

NeuralNetwork = MLPRegressor(verbose = True,
                             max_iter = 1000,
                             tol = 0,
                             activation = "logistic")
NeuralNetwork.fit(X, y)
```

The code works now, but the results are not correct as you will need to work on the features and your network hyperparameters. But this is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Worked here ! If I use MLPClassifier with this exact code you post, still don't work, is working just with Regressor, I found this very funny and non-sense(from a beginner point of view). Thank you for helping me, I'll try to learn about Regressor and the differences between theses metrics !